# Legend overwritten by plot - matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, line-plot

I have a plot that looks as follows:
[image]

I want to put labels for both the lineplot and the markers in red. However the legend is not appearning because its the plot is taking out its space.

**Update**

it turns out I cannot put several strings in `plt.legend()`

I made the figure bigger by using the following:

```
 fig = plt.gcf()
 fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
```

However now I have only one label in the legend, with the marker appearing on the lineplot while I rather want two: one for the marker alone and another for the line alone:

[image]

Updated code:

```
plt.plot(range(len(y)), y, '-bD',  c='blue', markerfacecolor='red', markeredgecolor='k', markevery=rare_cases, label='%s' % target_var_name)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)

# changed this over here
plt.legend()

plt.savefig(output_folder + fig_name)
plt.close()
```

Comment: I may be wrong but the legend is there! it's the gray square at top right.

Comment: @gboffi yes, how can I make it appear properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do (have two labels for a single object) is not completely impossible but it's MUCH easier to plot separately the line and the rare values, e.g.

```
# boilerplate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# synthesize some data 
N = 501
t = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
s = np.sin(np.pi*t)
rare = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool); rare[:20]=True; np.random.shuffle(rare)

plt.plot(t, s, label='Curve')
plt.scatter(t[rare], s[rare], label='rare')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Update

> [...] it turns out I cannot put several strings in `plt.legend()`

Well, you can, as long as ① the several strings are in an iterable (a tuple or a list) and ② the number of strings (i.e., labels) equals the number of artists (i.e., thingies) in the plot.

```
plt.legend(('a', 'b', 'c'))
```